# How to get specific elements from an object to use them as props for a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

Having a component that accepts some props:

```
<MyComponent first="first" second="second" third="third" />
```

We can create an object:

```
const mockData = {
  first: 'test1',
  second: 'test2',
  third: 'test3'
};
```

and use it as props in the following way: `<MyComponent {...mockData} />` and it works fine.

What I want is to use just first two elements from the `mockData` object as none of them are required/mandatory it should not be a problem.

So I've tried like this: `<MyComponent {...mockData.first, ...mockData.second} />` but it doesn't work.

Of course it can be written like `<MyComponent first={mockData.first} second={mockData.second} />` but this is just an example with few elements as my real problem has more elements.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: <MyComponent {...mockData} />

Comment: Did you try to use `Pick<mockdate

Comment: You can write a function to extract only what you want. JavaScript does not have `... but only the first two` syntax. And note that even "first two" does not necessarily mean what you think it does, because property ordering is dictated by rules in the runtime and it's not (in a practical sense) under your control.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a type derived of mock data like:

```
type MyComponentType = Pick<mockdata, "first">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object spread syntax:

```js
const {third, ...rest} = mockData;

// now the variable rest has all the properties from mockData except third

<MyComponent {...rest}/>
```

Since you said you have many more properties, you can extract as many properties you want by simply including them before the destructuring, eg:

```js
const {third, fourth, fifth, /* etc */ ...rest} = mockData;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  const mockData = {
    first: 'test1',
    second: 'test2',
    third: 'test3'
  };


<MyComponent props={ mockData } />

const MyComponent = ({first, second, third}) => {
  return (
  <div>
    first = {first}
    second = {second}
    third = {third}
  </div>
)};
```

this should work for you

Comment: Please better to give more explanation